# A clarification about $\mathbf{Ab}(G_{ab},A)\cong\mathbf{Grp}(G,U(A))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Here is an example from p.45 in [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf):

[image]

As far as I understand, in the definition of $\mathbf{Ab}(G_{ab},A)\cong\mathbf{Grp}(G,U(A))$,  $\bar \phi$ is not quite $\bar \phi$. It constructed as follows. Consider $\phi:G\to U(A)$. This group homomorphism is also a group homomorphism $\phi':G\to A$. Now by the universal property, there is $\bar {\phi'}$. So $\bar \phi$ should actually be $\bar{\phi'}$, right?

Also I don't understand where the author omitted the symbol $U$ in the diagram. The universal property says that for any abelian group $A$ and any homomorphism $\phi:G\to A$ there is a unique $\bar \phi$ that makes the diagram commute. So it doesn't look like $A$ should be replaced by $U(A)$. And $G$ is any group, abelian or not, so I don't think it should be $U(G)$.

Comment: What do you view $U$ as doing?

Comment: @DerekElkins Forgetting the property of being abelian.

Comment: Okay, but *how* does it do this? You say, for example, that "it doesn't look like $A$ should be replaced by $U(A)$". Why not?

Comment: @DerekElkins I don't know how to formalize "how" it does this. For the second question, what I had in mind was that the universal property says "for any abelian group..." and it doesn't say that we have to regard that group as a non-abelian group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the name $U$ is not the best here. Often $\iota$ or something similar will be used for inclusions. *This need not be trivial.* Nevertheless, for a typical definition of $\mathbf{Ab}$ and $\mathbf{Grp}$, $\iota$ is a pure inclusion, i.e. $\iota(A)=A$ and $\iota(\varphi)=\varphi$. The point, of course, is that the $\iota$ makes it clear that we're restricting to abelian groups. The "correct" diagram that Leinster alludes to (using $\iota$ instead of $U$) is: $$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>\eta>> \iota(G_{ab}) \\
@| @VV\iota(\bar\varphi)V \\
G @>>\varphi> \iota(A)
\end{CD}$$ (written as a square due to typographical limitations). Or to write out the formula, it states: $$\forall A\in\mathsf{Ob}(\mathbf{Ab}).\forall\varphi\in\mathbf{Grp}(G,\iota(A)).\exists!\bar\varphi\in\mathbf{Ab}(G_{ab},A).\varphi=\iota(\bar\varphi)\circ\eta$$

We could omit the $\iota$s given that $\iota(H)=H$ and $\iota(\psi)=\psi$ for all $H$ and $\psi$. However, there are several reasons not to. First, $\iota$ may *not* be trivial in which case we can't omit it. Second, it makes clearer the connection to the general case of a universal property/adjunction. Third, it's nice to have a name for the inclusion so we *can* say things like $(-)_{ab}\dashv\iota$. Fourth, having $\iota$ be explicit means we don't need to write off to the side "for all Abelian groups $A$". Instead, this information is made explicit in the diagram. $A$ (and $G$) are free to be anything that makes the diagram "type check". Fifth, generally it is pleasant to write expressions that "type check".

To illustrate the difference in explicitness,
$$\begin{CD}
G @>\eta>> G_{ab} \\
@| @VV\bar\varphi V \\
G @>>\varphi> H
\end{CD}$$ seems like a completely sensible diagram when $H$ is non-abelian while $$\begin{CD}
G @>\eta>> \iota(G_{ab}) \\
@| @VV\iota(\bar\varphi)V \\
G @>>\varphi> \iota(H)
\end{CD}$$ is nonsense. Of course, you have to know what $\iota$ is, but at least you know that you need to know as opposed to some remark in some text that you could easily skim past.

I don't understand why you think we should have $\phi'$ instead of $\phi$. Either $\phi'$ is literally the same as $\phi$ in which case what's the problem? Or $\phi$ is different from $\phi'$ (because $\iota$ isn't trivial) in which case we definitely want $\phi$ not $\phi'$ which may not even exist.

Comment: The way you stated the universal property makes my $\phi'$ unnecessary. But I assume you knew its "categorical" version. How could the reader who only knows the "algebraic" version that Leinster states figure out that for example quantification in the universal property is taken over arrows in $\mathbf{Grp}$ and not in $\mathbf{Ab}$? Also, if one doesn't know the "categorical" version of the universal property, I don't see how they could figure out where $U$ is omitted in the diagram.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that you don't know what the diagrams imply. An arrow in a diagram is an arrow in a category, so its end points must be in the same category. You're told $G$ is a group and you're told $G_{ab}$ is an abelian group (and generally, that $(-)_{ab}:\mathbf{Grp}\to\mathbf{Ab}$), therefore $\eta:G\to G_{ab}$ should be an arrow of $\mathbf{Grp}$ (or perhaps $\mathbf{Ab}$) but $G_{ab}$ isn't an object of $\mathbf{Grp}$ so something's awry. It's pretty obvious that the inclusion should be used to rectify this even without Leinster explicitly saying that is what is omitted.

Comment: This is the "type checking" I refer to. These inclusions can typically be inferred along the lines of the above. Nevertheless, I'm not arguing for this abuse of notation. I often argue against it. The loose notation often used in Leinster is one of the problems I have with it (though it does some other things very well). That said, while I wouldn't have written it the way Leinster does, he provides more than enough information to resolve what's going on.

Comment: Now I see. I treated the diagram (as well as the universal property) as an excerpt from an algebra textbook, since I thought that he's merely giving some background from algebra, but I should have treated it categorically. Then it's indeed clear where $U$s are omitted.